# JavaFX charts CSS property "-fx-bar-fill" — what exactly does it do?

Tags: java, css, charts, javafx

I like the styling of the bars that comes with using `-fx-bar-fill` in my CSS code. However, there is a situation which calls for a bit of customization (I need one of my series' bars to have an striped pattern instead of merely a color). However, without using `-fx-bar-fill` the bars loose a number of properties beyond just the color, causing them to not match.

[image]

What is it exactly that `-fx-bar-fill` does? What are the individual properties such that I can re-apply them manually, if possible?

With `-fx-bar-fill`, you only specify a single color. From there it seems to then add:

**(Working)**

- A linear gradient based on the color specified (`-fx-background-color: linear-gradient()`)
- A border color slightly darker than the color of specified (`-fx-border-color: linear-gradient()`)

**(Not fully working)**

- An inner glow linear gradient slightly lighter than the color specified (`-fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box,#00FF00,2,0,0,0);`?)

I can't seem to fully replicate the inner glow on a gradient. Is there another way to do it? Are there any other effects in `-fx-bar-fill` which I might be missing?

Zoomed version:

[image]

Comment: Answered with a description of how `-fx-bar-fill` works. However, when I run an example I see no border like you describe. Can you post a [MCVE] to show what you are doing to get that border (and to explain your question more clearly)?

Comment: Might be because of java version differences. I'm running this on 1.7.0_75, which uses caspian.css? *edit:* Yep! looks like that was it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fx-bar-fill` is not a property, but a looked-up color (essentially a CSS variable that holds a color value; see the [CSS documentation for the color type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) and scroll down just past the table of predefined color-swatches).

This looked-up color is used in setting the `-fx-background-color` property of the bars in the bar chart, which are implemented as regions. From the [source code for modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css):

```
.chart-bar {
    -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_1;
    -fx-background-color:   linear-gradient(to right, 
                                derive(-fx-bar-fill, -4%),
                                derive(-fx-bar-fill, -1%),
                                derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%),
                                derive(-fx-bar-fill, -1%),
                                derive(-fx-bar-fill, -6%)
                              );
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

So this sets the value of `-fx-bar-fill` to another looked-up color, `CHART_COLOR_1` (more in a moment), and then defines the background color of the bars in the bar chart to a (very subtle) linear gradient whose color stops are based on its value.

Colors for bars in other series are set differently by redefining the value of `-fx-bar-fill` for bars in those other series:

```
.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_1; }
.default-color1.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_2; }
.default-color2.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_3; }
.default-color3.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_4; }
.default-color4.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_5; }
.default-color5.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_6; }
.default-color6.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_7; }
.default-color7.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: CHART_COLOR_8; }
```

and those individual colors are defined as

```
CHART_COLOR_1: #f3622d;
CHART_COLOR_2: #fba71b;
CHART_COLOR_3: #57b757;
CHART_COLOR_4: #41a9c9;
CHART_COLOR_5: #4258c9;
CHART_COLOR_6: #9a42c8;
CHART_COLOR_7: #c84164;
CHART_COLOR_8: #888888;
```

So the net result is that, for the first series, the bar starts at the left edge with a color 4% darker than `#f3622d`, lightens (in a non-linear way) to `#f3622d` at the center, and then darkens by 6% to the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

[James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) led me to the answer with his post above. I would only add (for the record) that his java version (8_u60) is newer than mine (7_u75), which uses a different CSS file for styling the bar charts. To provide the answer specific to my java version (i.e. to get my exact result in terms of how the bars are styled for me), the CSS for the `-fx-bar-fill` is as follows:

```
.chart-bar {
    -fx-bar-fill: #22bad9;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)),
                          linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)),
                          linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
}
```